# How to create / call a mysql event from hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using `spring , hibernate`. I need that when update a status to "A", an event executes after a day.
My question is: How to create the `event` from `Java` and?
I have been doing this:

```
Date endDate = cal.getTime();
    Timestamp time = new Timestamp(endDate.getTime());

    String sql = "CREATE EVENT EVENT_POLL ON SCHEDULE AT " + time +
            " DO UPDATE POLL SET STATUS = 'F' WHERE ID = " + dto.getId();
    System.out.println("SQL: " + sql);
    springHibernateDao.getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
```

I got this `error`:

> ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - No value specified for parameter 1

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible.

An alternative method is to create an event from the command line in the following structure:

- Create an event that runs every minute/hour etc according to what your hibernate code was creating except that this event runs at a regular interval and not just once;
- Create a table in which you place your run instruction with the scheduled time it should run;
- Use hibernate to insert the instruction into that table;
- Let your event check that table and run the code from there.